# Database recording users' consent to be subject to commands of other users

Tags: database, postgresql

I am adding a database to my application that fulfils these requirements:

- There is a set of users and a set of commands.
- Each user can consent to any number of other users to have commands done on them.
- Consent is not bidirectional.
- Each user can consent to either all commands being done on them or just some (or 1).

Here's the schema I managed to obtain:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE commands (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE user_consents (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  user_id BIGINT REFERENCES users(id),
  receiver_id BIGINT REFERENCES users(id),
  is_all_commands BOOLEAN DEFAULT false,
  UNIQUE (user_id, receiver_id)
);

CREATE TABLE user_command_consents (
  user_consent_id BIGINT REFERENCES user_consents(id)
  ON UPDATE CASCADE
  ON DELETE CASCADE,
  command_id INTEGER REFERENCES commands(id),
  PRIMARY KEY (user_consent_id, command_id)
);


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_user_consent_all_commands()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
  IF (SELECT is_all_commands FROM user_consents WHERE id = NEW.user_consent_id) THEN
RAISE EXCEPTION 'Cannot give consent for specific commands if all commands are consented';
  END IF;
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER check_user_consent_all_commands
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON user_command_consents
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE FUNCTION check_user_consent_all_commands();
```

The idea behind this schema is to use a flag to tell us whether we should assume all commands (or just some). If all, then the record is limited to only the `user_consents` relation. If not, the flag is false and to get all of the commands for a user with id of `neededUserID` we need to get all of the rows with `user_command_consents.user_consent_id = user_consents.id` where `user_consents.user_id = neededUserID`.

Is this good?

Comment: Upon second thought this design is ass. We may have a 100 commands and a user One who gives consent to user Two for 99 of those commands. Thus we will need to store 99 rows in the user_command_consents relation. More thought required.